# how to know the credential used by network drive mapping?

Tags: windows, network-shares

In windows network drive mapping could use any credential -- it could be local user, or a domain user, so long as the id and password are keyed-in, and ticked the "remember the credential" and "reconnect at login" checkboxes.

I wonder, after logged in windows, is it possible to check, for each network drive, which id is used for mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check on the target computer, which user account was used to create the connection.
There's a Windows tool `fsmgmt.msc`, try that.

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14834928/1453710

> wmic netuse where LocalName="Z:" get UserName /value